# Sum amounts of Sales

Tags: sql, firebird2.5

I want to select items and sum their sales and price like:

```
Produkt Sales   Price
Car1    1       100
Car1    2       120
Car1    3       110
Car2    1       200
Car2    2       210
```

Result should be

```
Produkt Sales   Price
Car1    6       330
Car2    3       410
```

I know the sum function, but I cant get out how I select the simular Cars to group them to sum the numbers.

Comment: `GROUP BY col` means "give me one result line per col", and this is exactly what you want. Hence: `GROUP BY produkt`. Then get the aggregates you want, i.e. `SUM(sales)` and `SUM(price)`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `GROUP` your results on column `produkt` and use `sum()` aggregate function to calculate `sales` and `prices` for each group.

This is ANSI SQL, so it works not only in `Firebird`.

```
SELECT produkt, SUM(sales) as sales, SUM(price) as price
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY produkt
ORDER BY produkt
```

Comment: Works! On thing: As soon I ad another colum like "Brand" my editor puts this into the group section too: "GROUP BY produkt   brand" and after that its not grouping anymore.

Comment: @Michael Müller: Your table contains product prices. It should not contain the brand, as it makes no sense for a product to have different brands for different prices. So the error indicates a bad database model. [to be continued] ...

Comment: @Michael Müller: ... If it were a different column, e.g. last_sold_by, indicating who last sold the product for the stated price, you'd have to decide: Do you want one result line per produkt and last_sold_by? Or do you still want one line per produkt? In case of the latter: Which last_sold_by to display for a product? The first in alphabetical order? Or simply the distinct number of sellers? This is what is happening here: You cannot have last_sold_by (or brand in your case) in your select list, without having it in your GROUP BY clause. So: Either group by a column or aggregate it.

Comment: I guess i understand. I get the tbale as it is. So that means i would have to splitt the table into sales and cars and brands? and then select it later to combin it again?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Produkt, SUM(Sales) AS Total_sales, SUM(Price) as Total_price
FROM table_name --Your table name here
GROUP BY Produkt
ORDER BY Produkt
```

Try this SQL